# Shell script to compare result with a text file?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Currently when I execute getent database, it will give me a result in the following form:

```
    string1,string2,string3,string4,string5
```

I have a text file that has everything in this format:

```
    string1,number
    string2,number
    string3,number
```

Everytime I run my shell script, I want to get the content of my database and compare with the text file. If there are new strings in the database that do not exit in my text file, I want to write the new string at the end of my text with a random number so the text file will become:

```
    string1,number
    string2,number
    string3,number
    string4,number
    string5,number
```

Pretty new to shell..what's the best way and syntax I should look into?

Comment: Is the `string1,string2,string3,string4,string5`input to a script?

Comment: It is output of the comamnd "getent database" http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/getent.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Basics

Taking this output from `getent` as an example:

```
$ getent passwd daemon
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

We can process it as you request via:

```
$ getent passwd daemon | while IFS=: read s1 s2 s3 rest; do printf "%s,%s\n" $s1 $RANDOM $s2 $RANDOM $s3 $RANDOM; done
daemon,7721
x,9604
1,2061
```

#### How it works

- `getent passwd daemon`

  Replace this with whatever `getent` command that generates the data that want.
- `|`

  This tells the shell to feed the output of `getent` to the input of the next command.
- `while IFS=: read s1 s2 s3 rest; do`

  This starts a `while` loop by reading four variables from the next line of standard input.  Since the output of `getent` is colon-separated, we set `IFS` to be `:`.

  In the question, you show the output of `getent` being comma separated.  If that were the case, then replace `IFS=:` with `IFS=,`.
- `printf "%s,%s\n" $s1 $RANDOM $s2 $RANDOM $s3 $RANDOM`

  This prints the first three string variables output with random numbers added.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the `while` loop.

#### Multi-line from

For those who prefer their shell commands spread over multiple lines:

```
getent passwd daemon | while IFS=: read s1 s2 s3 rest
do
    printf "%s,%s\n" $s1 $RANDOM $s2 $RANDOM $s3 $RANDOM
done
```

### Comparing and updating a reference file

This will check for the existence of any of the first three strings in `testfile` and append to `testfile` those which were not already there:

```
getent passwd daemon | while IFS=: read s1 s2 s3 rest; do for s in "$s1" "$s2" "$s3"; do grep -qE "^$s," testfile || printf '%s,%s\n' "$s" "$RANDOM">>testfile; done; done
```

Or, in multi-line form:

```
getent passwd daemon | while IFS=: read s1 s2 s3 rest
do
    for s in "$s1" "$s2" "$s3"
    do
        grep -qE "^$s," testfile || printf '%s,%s\n' "$s" "$RANDOM">>testfile
    done
done
```

Comment: What if I don't know how many variables will be in my output of getent? It could be 4 or 5 or 6 but the number is changing. Also, how should I open a text file and compare which variable already exist and write the one that does not exit into the file?

Comment: The above works regardless of whether the output has 4, 5, or 6 fields.  You asked for the output to have "random numbers."  What do you want to happen when those random numbers are "compared" with data in an existing file?

Comment: The  numbers are not compared, but the variables before the numbers are compared so basically s1, s2, s3 are compared against the strings in a text file

Comment: OK.  Answer updated to compare against an existing file.

Answer (score 1):

Get to know bash associative arrays set by `declare -A`, and in particular the difference between the following two statements:

```
echo 'A: ${strings[@]}='"${strings[@]}";
echo 'B: ${!strings[@]}='"${!strings[@]}";
```

A quick search for bash associative arrays turned up [this tutorial](http://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/).

As you are new to bash also look at:

1. `IFS` environment variable and how it impacts the read function.
2. lines like: `for num in ${numbers//,/ }; do  echo $num; done;`

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure I understood your problem statement.
But from what I could understand, this might work:

```
$ cat file1
string1,number1
string2,number2
string3,number3

$ cat file2
string1,string2,string3,string4,string5


$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; print; next}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if (!($i in a)) print $i"," (int(10000*rand()));}' file1 file2

string1,number1
string2,number2
string3,number3
string4,2377
string5,2910
```

Notes:
Number 10000 used here is just an arbitrary number. Change as required.
Also, due to an inherent issue, these random numbers can get repeated if the number of records is large.

Code explanation:
Record existing "string"s in an array named `a` for the first file. During file2 processing, if the entry is not found in array a, print a new entry with random number.